# what is the difference between virtual platform and real platform

Tags: vmware, platform

I have a application running on my system(pc) which has OS windows 7, if I run the same application in a virtual machine on VMWare running Windows 7 OS. Here are my questions:

1. If my application is running on my system what is platform here? I mean what is the name of platform?
2. If my application is running on virtual machine platform vmwAre, where I can see the platform?
3. What is the difference between platform and OS?

Comment: Platform is just a generic term for OS in most cases. There can be a case made that the Platform is Windows and the OS is Windows 7. Sometimes platform can refer to the kernel, but only sometimes. In both situations, both should be identical.

Comment: i dont think so,platform is combination of software and hardware,,for eg: windows xp 32 bit is a platform where windows xp is software (OS) and 32 bit hard ware,,but i still have doubts thats why i asked question i need a clear solution

Comment: It's vmwAre, not vmwire.

Comment: You can still have 32-bit Windows installed on 64-bit hardware. Platform is one of those buzzwords that is given a different definition by everybody. VMWare emulates hardware. It basically lies to the OS. You can install either a 32-bit or 64-bit OS in a VM assuming you have a 64-bit CPU and appropriate BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the difference between platform and OS?**

I cannot think of an *official definition* for platform. Platform can mean different things to different people depending on the context:

1. you can create applications for .net platform which may imply you're using Windows, but not the version (you may use mono on Linux as well)
2. the Java platform provides a basis for Java application, but does not tell you anything about JDK version, middleware products, etc
3. storage plaforms like SAN, NAS, etc
4. Virtualization platforms may consist of several components: hardware, storage, host OS, guest OS, etc.

Given your question I'd use the term *platform* as 'something above the OS':

Physical platform: Windows 7 + physical h/w

Virtual platform: VMWare + host OS + guest OS (Windows 7) + phyiscal h/w + virtual h/w

my 0.02 $

Comment: so you mean here virtual platform means,  Vmware hardware +windows 7 OS

Comment: @ricky: as I tried to explain, this it what it means to me. Others may have a different opinion. BTW: You should distinguish between physical h/w (host capacity) and virtual h/w (capacity available to guests).

Comment: VMWare provides virtualization software in different flavours, it's not h/w (hardware)?

Comment: one more question where we can see virtual hardware,is it in cloud??

Comment: @Ricky: The h/w you see in a virtual OS is not necessarily "real" h/w. Let's say you see 4GB RAM in your virtual OS, this does not mean that those 4GB are exclusively mapped to your OS, e.g. it may be shared between different virtual OSes (same applies for CPUs (vCPU)). Cloud is only a buzzword, at the end it's good old computers as well...

Answer (score 0):

The word "Platform" is market-speak which is leaking into tech-speak; perhaps via your question ;)

My understanding of the word platform is that it comprises all of the components mentioned by you. Which means hardware+OS+Application Software nad sometimes +network is called a platform.

For example; a Web Development platform consists of a Web Server, an Application Server, A Development IDE (or whatever) and perhaps a Code Repository/sub-versioning system.

The Virtual Machine or the Operating system are just components of a Platform.

YMMV - Others may have different understanding of the word. No warranties expressed or implied :)